# Query Mongo based on query string with match or regex

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, database

Im trying to query mongo, and query's based on a specific field, such as a username or country, it returns only that match. I can get the data i want on a get request, but whenever I try to query by specific field it breaks. It will return this error.

my query string : localhost:4002/users?firstName=Mark

err: MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: firstName: { $match: "Mark" }

```
  app.get('/users', (req,res) => {
    co(function*(){
      var dbSocial = yield MongoClient.connect(dbSocialUrl);

      let query = {

          firstName:1,
          lastName:1,
          createDT:1,
          "_mailAddress.country":1,
          ownerId:1,
          userName:1
      }
      //
      if (req.query.firstName) {
        query["firstName"] = {
          $match: req.query.firstName || '',
        }
      }

      console.log('query',query);

      //get users
      var users = yield dbSocial
        .collection('user')
        .find({},(query))
        .limit(100)
        .toArray();
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with my query object.

```
let query ={}
```

Works

Answer (score 0):

$match is a Aggregation Pipeline Operators that takes a document that specifies the query conditions. It takes an object as a query.

*{ $match: { <> } }*

You should put the fields that you want match, which is, in your case, **name**.
So build the query like,

*db.collection_name.aggregate({$match:{'name':'Mark'}})*